# How to add color to the left side of the bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add the color to the left side of the bootstrap card like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNmxL.png)

but I don't no how to add can any one help me

Comment: add your html code to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your stylesheet:

```
border-left: 2px solid blue;
```